# How to write raster files to ENVI format as BIP

Tags: r, rgdal, r-raster

I want to stack and write some Landsat bands/tiff files to BIP interleave in ENVI format. However, the results always come as BSQ, even though I change the bandorder to BIP.

Below is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

inbands <-list.files(pattern= "*.tif")
stk<-stack(inbands[2], inbands[3], inbands[4])
writeRaster(stk, "BIP_test", format="ENVI", bandorder='BIP')
```

### This also did not work

```
writeRaster(stk, "BIP_test", format="ENVI",  options="INTERLEAVE=PIXEL", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
writeRaster(stk, "BIP_test", format="ENVI",  options="INTERLEAVE=BIP", overwrite=TRUE)
```

per the [GDAL formats page on the ENVI format](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ENVI), "BIP" (not "PIXEL") is the argument to "INTERLEAVE". Based on my reading of the `WriteRaster` helpfile, `bandorder='BIP'` only works for the raster package's native file format.